# Problems with error The specified child already has a parent. You must call .... on Android

Tags: android, layout, view

I've been having a ton of errors of this kind. The problem is that I can't for the life of me figure out who is the parent of the View I'm trying to add. My question is: Is there any way to check who is the parent of the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view.getParent() method will tell you if the view you're trying to add already has a parent.

```
ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
   ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(view);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is wonderfull to make sure a View that will add has no more parents!! One thing though In order for the code to compile I had to use: ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(view);